# how do I import a microsoft outlook calendar to my html website

Tags: web-services, calendar, outlook

I'm developing a website using visual studios and I want the ability to view my microsoft outlook calendar from my website. How can I import calendar info to my website? Is there a soap call I can use?

Or: I know that outlook uses .ics files to hold data. Any chance I could maybe import an .ics file and use that to create a calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has written a windows app that you install on the client machine that runs outlook called Google Calendar Synch.  Then you create a Google web calendar online and Google Calendar Synch will synch your Outlook calendar with your Google web calendar.  Then you embed the Google web calendar into your website.

See this CNET article for an overview:

http://news.cnet.com/8301-33620_3-57440246-278/google-your-bridge-from-outlook-to-any-smartphones-calendar/

No coding or messy human imports or exports of ICS files needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this was accurate when answered, Google Sync is no longer available. It was retired in Aug 2014.